# Google Polymer paper-fab on-tap start download

Tags: javascript, firebase, polymer, firebase-storage

Description: I have a paper-fab on my page. I am calling firebase-storage call inside a ready function so that I can get a link to a pdf file stored on firebase storage service.Once I get a link I assign it to the iframe (maybe I'm doing this wrong) and append it to the body.

The question that I have is, is there a way to do this without using iframe? If so how would I do it? If not, what should I do to make the existing code work?

Below are the polymer component and call I'm making inside ready life cycle.

```html
<paper-fab mini icon="file-download" id="fileDownload" on-click="downloadFile"></paper-fab>

<firebase-storage id="storage" app-name="website" path="/path-to-pdf-file"></firebase-storage>
```

```js
downloadFile: function() {
    // Create an IFRAME.
    var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");

    // Point the IFRAME to GenerateFile
    iframe.src = this.filepath;

    // This makes the IFRAME invisible to the user.
    iframe.style.display = "none";

    // Add the IFRAME to the page.  This will trigger a request to GenerateFile now.
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
  },

  ready: function() {
    const storage = this.$.storage;
    storage.getDownloadUrl(storage.path).then(function(url) {
      this.filepath = url;
    }.bind(this)).catch(function(err) {
      console.debug('something really bad happened');
    });
  }
```

Using iframe I get this error.

> web-home.html:97 Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/pdf:

Help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one simple solution

```
<a href="path/to/download">
    <paper-fab></paper-fab>
</a>
```